# Entity Framework return empty set

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm working on simple ASP .NET MVC Application. I have a simple local database in it. This database contains a few tables. I made model, view and controller for one of this table. I also made DBContext class and Connection string. Everything seems work fine except that using context from controller return empty set. I'm sure that table contains at least one record. I don't know what is wrong.

There's my Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SportsVenues] (
[Id]           INT            NOT NULL,
[Name]         NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Description]  TEXT           NOT NULL,
[Country]      NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[City]         NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[Street]       NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[Area]         DECIMAL (18)   NULL,
[PictureUrl]   NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[OppeningYear] DATETIME       NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

There's model:

```
[Table("SportsVenues")]
public class SportsVenue
{
    [Column("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public double Area { get; set; }
    public DateTime OppeningYear { get; set; }
}
```

There's Database Context class:

```
public class StecSportsDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<StecSports.Models.Trick> Tricks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StecSports.Models.Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StecSports.Models.SportsVenue> Venues { get; set; }
}
```

And there's my connection string:

```
<add name="StecSportsDBContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\StecSports.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

I've also checked query send to database, and after type it in new query page it return data as expected. I'm using visual studio 2012 on windows 7. 
How can I get data stored in database? What I'm doing wrong?

As  Eric J. requested In controller I simply use property venues from DbContext class:

```
ViewBag.venuesList = db.Venues;
```

which is initialized as:

```
private StecSportsDBContext db = new StecSportsDBContext();
```

And it gives me sql query like this:

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Country] AS [Country], 
[Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
[Extent1].[Street] AS [Street], 
[Extent1].[Area] AS [Area], 
[Extent1].[OppeningYear] AS [OppeningYear]
FROM [SportsVenues] AS [Extent1]}
```

I'm sure this query works and return right data, because I copied it and run on database server.

Comment: You showed everything but the code that actually tries to query the database.

Comment: I simply use function from context like ViewBag.venuesList = db.Venues; It gives me sql query like {SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Country] AS [Country], 
[Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
[Extent1].[Street] AS [Street], 
[Extent1].[Area] AS [Area], 
[Extent1].[OppeningYear] AS [OppeningYear]
FROM [SportsVenues] AS [Extent1]}. db variable is intialized as  private StecSportsDBContext db = new StecSportsDBContext();

Comment: Please edit your question with that code rather than adding a comment.

Comment: Make absolutely sure that you're accessing exactly the same database at runtime that you think you are. Check full path of the database at runtime. I spent two full days fighting this issue in the past week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enumerate your query. You can use `.ToList()` to get your results.

```
ViewBag.venuesList = db.Venues.ToList();
```

Comment: Actually db.Venues.Count() returns 0. I think something is wrong with my connection string.

Comment: after instantiating your context, check your connection string to make sure it is picking it up from the config correctly: `db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`

Comment: It's ok. This same as I've puted into Web.config file.

Comment: did you get anywhere after this ?